# Getting IncompatibleArguments error for a map<json> arg in Ballerina

Tags: json, ballerina

```
public type Field record {|
    string name;
    FieldType 'type;
|};

public type QueryType record {|
    string name;
    string description?;
    Field[] args;
|};

public type ObjectType record {|
    string name;
    Field[] fields;
|};

public type ConstructQueryInput record {|
    string task;
    QueryType querySchema;
    ObjectType[] objectTypeSchemas;
|};

public function constructGraphQLQuery(ConstructQueryInput input) returns json|error {
    // function implementation omitted for clarity
    return {"output": "successfully executed function"};
}
```

We are calling the `constructGraphQLQuery` function which is defined in above code as shown below.

```
any|error observation = function:call(constructGraphQLQuery, input);
```

The type of the argument `input` is `map<json> & readonly`.
When the value of the optional field in `input` is null, we get an IncompatibleArguments error. The value is shown as below.

```
{
        objectTypeSchemas: [
            {
                name: "",
                fields: [
                    {
                        name: "",
                        'type: "TWO"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        task: "test",
        querySchema: {
            name: "",
            description: null, // optional field as NULL
            args: [
                {
                    name: "",
                    'type: "TWO"
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

An optional field `string description?;` means the description field may or may not be present, but if present it will be a string value. To allow nil/null the type has to allow nil.

E.g.,

- `string? description;` - if the field is always present and the value can be string or nil
- `string? description?;` - if the field may or may not be present, and when present can be string or nil